# unable to find matching constructor for: java.time.ZonedDateTime()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, testng, java-time

i have a very simple code base and i feel really silly here. Why am i getting the error `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.time.ZonedDateTime()`

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
class timeTests {
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.class.getName())
    def startTime(){
        return new ZonedDateTime().now()
    }
    def endTime(){
        def start = startTime()
        def end = start.plusSeconds(5)
        return end
    }
    @Test
    void test(){
        log.info(endTime())
    }
}
```

example taken from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zoneddatetime-now-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: [`return ZonedDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--)?

Comment: “example taken from…” I don’t see `new ZonedDateTime` anywhere on that geeksforgeeks page.

Comment: No i rewrote it instead of copy/paste :) Only way i learn @VGR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor does not exist. Use `ZonedDateTime.now()` or one of the equivalents. See the relevant [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).